# Is there any way to use Pod methods inside a different Pod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm writing an app in Xcode that analyses colours drawn via touch. It uses a drawing framework, "MaLiang", that I've installed into my project via CocoaPods. As the touch tracking/drawing function is based in this Pod, I've been writing my analysis code into its touchesMoved function, but I want to trigger audio alongside the drawing using a different framework, AudioKit.

I've tried installing Audiokit to my project using my Podfile, but MaLiang won't recognise AudioKit as existing within the project if I try and import it at the top of the class in question. Is there any way I can import and use these other Pod methods and classes within this Pod? Any help would be massively appreciated!

Here's my file organiser if that helps:
[File organiser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STxuO.png)

EDIT: Thanks for the help, I believe the issue I'm having is with AudioKit rather than developing these pods locally as I can't even get AudioKit Playgrounds in a seperate project to work without throwing the "Failed to load module AudioKit" error.

Comment: MaLiang doesn't use AudioKit.  Show us the code in your app that doesn't work as expected

Comment: I know it doesn't normally, I'm trying to add AudioKit to MaLiang if that makes sense?
It registers AudioKit as existing now that I've added AudioKit to 'Link Binary With Libraries' in the the Pods build settings, but gives me a thousand different errors when I try to compile, starting with "Failed to load module" after I try and import AudioKit. That's the thing throwing an error, my code compiles as soon as I remove it

Comment: You cannot alter a pod’s code, so what are we even talking about here?

Comment: You could download the MaLiang source code and manually add it into your project, then you should have control over importing AudioKit into MaLiang. Or better yet, use Gereon's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply changing an imported Pod's code locally is a bad idea - you run the risk of losing all your changes when you run `pod update` or `pod install`.

If you want your changes to persist, you should fork MaLiang and add your forked repo (or for easier development, its path) to your Podfile.

To add code that uses AudioKit to MaLiang, you will first need to add

```
s.dependency 'AudioKit'
```

to your fork's [podspec](https://github.com/Harley-xk/MaLiang/blob/master/MaLiang.podspec).

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, thank you - I'm very new to CocoaPods so I'm just flailing around in the dark here. 
I managed to add a local podspec adding AudioKit as a dependency to MaLiang, but I'm still getting the same batch of errors referring to AudioKit, like "'AKNode' is not a member type of 'AudioKit'" and "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass". 

These errors are thrown even when I try and import AudioKit into my main project View Controller, so maybe it's an issue with AK rather than Pods interacting?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, yes. Maybe ask that as a separate question, if you can reproduce it in a standalone project.